# How to extract text from two xml tags in one line using lxml

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I want to extract simple text using lxml for example

```
<tables>
    <entry> some text </entry>
    <entry> more text </entry>
</table>
```

Now my desired output should be like this in one line

```
some text more text
```

The code i am trying is this:

```
from lxml import etree
f = open('doc.xml')
path = etree.parse(f)
f.close()
for text in doc.xpath('//entry/text()'):
    print text
```

The function like concatenate and string-join are not doing the job please suggest some simplest function that would give my desired output. Thank you.

```
from lxml import etree
from StringIO import StringIO
f = open('doc.xml')
xml = f.read()
doc = etree.parse(StringIO(xml))
f.close()
for txt in doc.xpath('//tables/table/entry/text()'):
    print txt
```

i am doing it in this way now i am confused where to use findall().

Comment: I updated my answer. In future stick to editing your own question and making comments, don't try editing someone's answer to communicate.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
from lxml import etree
from StringIO import StringIO

doc = etree.parse(StringIO("""
<tables>
    <table>
        <entry> some text </entry>
        <entry> more text </entry>
    </table>
    <table>
        <entry> further text </entry>
        <entry> even more text </entry>
    </table>
</tables>
"""))

for table in doc.findall('table'):
    line = ' '.join(entry.text.strip() for entry in table.findall('entry'))
    print(line)
```

Output:

```
some text more text
further text even more text
```

Comment: Sorry @Alex as i am new  here i am not much aware . I really appreciate your answer but i am using xpath and findall is nor working for me.

Comment: @uba I'm afraid I don't know xpath. You will have to elaborate how findall is not working for you.

Comment: Firstly you don't need `StringIO`, I used that to mimic a file to make a single standalone script. You can just use the file directly. Secondly why can't you just use my code as is?

Comment: Actually i am working with a large xml file and i have extracted my desired data the only problem i am facing is that i want text of two tags in one line . This just a small part of my code and i am doing this inside the loop(recursive loop). I have used the xpath approach from beginning, i am just unable to figure how could i concat or join lines of two tags . The answer you gave previously was very helpful i wish if you write that again . It was giving everything in one line some code like that could help may be.

Comment: @uba click on "edited 11 hours ago" to see the history. It's still not clear why you can't use the code that's there right now.

Comment: line = ' '.join(text.strip() for text in doc.xpath('//entry/text()'))
 this part of code is working a bit but it gives all the text from tags in one as i am looking to extract in iterable form. For example using for loop text from two tags in one line then text from other two tags in next line and so on.

Comment: @uba but that's what my current code does. What's wrong with the current code?

Comment: Yes the code you have written is working perfect but in my case i think i am messing up with the path . I am not giving the correct path in findall('....') i guess . Its giving this error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: OK this has gotten out of hand, post a fresh question with the latest code, a sample XML input file, and an explanation about what's wrong.